# Estimating regression parameters separately for each subject

Tags: regression, mixed-model, pooling

It seems to be a relatively common approach in some fields to,
for a linear relationship which is subject to individual differences,
estimate regression parameters separately for each subject in an
experiment, and then use one sample t tests to check if each parameter
is significantly different from $0$ across subjects.

Having done some work with mixed-effects models, however,
it's not clear to me how this approach is a justifiable alternative to a mixed-model.

For example, [Buchel et al (2011)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811911005398) report the following analysis

> [...] we tested whether the risk taken (that is, the number of boxes
>   opened) in round t + 1 can be predicted by the missed opportunity and
>   the position of the finally opened box at round t (risk) [...]:
>
> $$risk_{t+1}=c_0 + c_1missed\_opportunity_t + c_2 risk_t$$
>
> [...] The estimated regression coefficients $c$ were then tested for
>   significance in the whole group using a one sample t-test.

**How does this approach compare to fitting an appropriate mixed-effects model?**

`lmer(risk ~ prev_missed_opportunity + prev_risk + 
              (prev_missed_opportunity + prev_risk|subject))`

$$risk_{t+1}=\\ \beta_0 + \gamma_{0,S} + \\
 \beta_1 missed\_opportunity_t + \gamma_{1,S} missed\_opportunity_t +\\
\beta_2 risk_t + \gamma_{2,S} risk_t
$$

where $\beta_{0..2}$  are the "fixed effects", and $\gamma_{0..2,S}$ are the normally distributed deviation from the fixed effect estimate for subject $S$.

---

Some points:

- I understand that the mixed-effects model allows for partial pooling:
  coefficient estimates for participants who deviate from the rest of the group, or which have been estimated from a smaller sample, will shrink towards the population mean
- Each participant's regression coefficient in the original paper is an estimate, rather than a known data point. Intuition says that this matters in some way, but I don't know how.
- For what it's worth, in my own analysis, I've found that both methods result in roughly the same coefficient estimates, but the mixed-effects model yields lower standard errors, and thus lower p values.
- A number of other SE questions have touched on this issue

  - [fitting a model of each subject and perform a t-test over the estimated parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70006/42952) - concerns an analogous problem where an effect is positive for some subjects, but negative for others (again, mixed-effects models are proposed as a solution)
  - [Estimates of regression coefficients at subject- vs group-level](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/110047/42952) - discusses shrinkage, but makes no recommendations.
  - [Aggregate vs. firm-level regressions - How can the regression coefficients differ that much?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/66138/42952) - concerns Simpson's paradox, which may or may not be relevant here

Comment: Gelman calls this [the secret weapon](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2005/03/07/the_secret_weap/)